# The inverse in the sense of MOORE-PENROSAE $AA^{-1}B=B$

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

On which conditions we have
$$AA^{-1}B=B$$
A, B are nonnegative definite symmetric $n\times n-$matrices, and $A^{-1}$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse of A.

Comment: $A^{-1}$ denotes the Moore-Penrose inverse of $A$?

Comment: yeah it is the Moore-Penrose inverse of A

Comment: Then precisely if it is the regular inverse of $A$: If $A^{-1}$ is the inverse of $A$ then $A A^{-1} = I_n$ and thus $A A^{-1} B = B$. The other direction works similarly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me write $A^+$ for the Moore-Penrose inverse.

Then $AA^+$ is the [orthogonal projector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Projectors) onto the range of $A$.

Therefore $AA^+B=B$ iff the range of $B$ is contained in the range of $A$.